# I want to start a programming blog, what should I use?

Tags: open-source, cms, markdown, self-hosted, blog

Required features:

- Source code syntax highlighting
- I can write post using Markdown
- Open Source
- Installable on my server
- Written in Ruby or Python or JavaScript on server-side (plus JavaScript on client-side)

Nice to have (not very important to me at the moment):

- plugins

Comment: I'd rather say Python, because of the combination of Markdown and Code highlighting (corresponding libraries exist there, not sure for PHP concerning "codelite").

Answer (score 10):

I see more programmers using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) for their blogs lately. In ways, it covers the basics.

- [x] Source code syntax highlighting (You may want to check [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648390/syntax-highlighting-markdown-code-blocks-in-jekyll-without-using-liquid-tags))
- [x] Markdown
- [x] Free (it's closedly tied to free hosting in Github, via Github Pages)
- [x] Hackable
- [x] Plugins

I haven't done enough research on other platforms, but I am sure you can find others easily.

Comment: @bryan-chen [StackExchange recently moved their blog to Jekyll](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/how-we-built-our-blog/), and [the code can be found on Github](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog). That said, Jekyll seems like a very useful bit of software, especially for programmers. Hell, I think I'll give it a try soon!

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend [Nikola](http://getnikola.com/) - it is free, written in python and specifically offers:

- Blogs, with tags, feeds, archives, comments, etc.
- Themable
- Fast builds, thanks to doit
- Flexible, extensible via plugins
- Small codebase (programmers can understand all of Nikola core in a
  day)
- reStructuredText [Cheatsheet] or Markdown as input language (also
  Wiki, BBCode, Textile, AsciiDoc, Python Notebooks, Misaka, Pandoc,
  txt2tags, orgmode, and HTML)
- Easy image galleries (just drop files in a folder!)
- Syntax highlighting for almost any programming language or markup
- Multilingual sites, translated to 18 languages.

So hits all your question points.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [radiantCms](http://radiantcms.org/).

Although it's not a pure blogging platform, it definitely supports this functionality as shown
in the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_%28software%29#Design).

It offers Markdown during writing and like most CMSs and the ability to mess around the code.

Finally it has a large collection of [extensions](http://ext.radiantcms.org/extensions) where you can find something like [this](http://ext.radiantcms.org/extensions/110-code) for code highlighting and it's written in ruby ;).

Answer (score 4):

[Drupal](https://drupal.org/) can definitely do this if you use a couple extensions. Drupal (and generally speaking it's extensions) are in PHP/HTML/JavaScript. You'd want the [Markdown Filter](https://drupal.org/project/markdown) and the [Markdown Editor](https://drupal.org/project/markdowneditor) for [BUEditor](http://drupal.org/project/bueditor).

Drupal has [more plugins](https://drupal.org/project/project_module) than anyone could possibly use!

Answer (score 3):

[Ghost blogging platform](https://ghost.org/) is very good.  Apart from being open source and using markdown, it is lightweight with a beautiful minimalist them. it uses Nodejs for its back-end. It also support extensions. It is still being developed.